# Count clicks on Video PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, video

i have multiple different video's on my page which are uploaded to the database and are displayed to my page like this :

```
<div id="videoContainer">

    <?php
    $fetchVideos = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM content ORDER BY ID DESC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchVideos)) {
        $location = $row['Video'];

        echo "<div id='video' >";
        echo "<form method='post'>
                <input id='clickCounter' type='submit' name='click' value='click'>
                    <video src='" . $location . "' controls='' width='320px' height='200px' >
                </input>
              </form>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['click'])) {
        $query = "UPDATE content SET clicks = clicks +1 WHERE ID = '2'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }
    ?>

</div>
```

As you can i already added a button to increase the clicks by 1 every time i click it, that works fine , but it has to happen when i click on play on the video.

the video' all have different ID's

Comment: `i have multiple different video's on my page` But all of them appear to have an ID of 2 ???

Comment: RiggsFolly no they all have different id's that's only to test if the increase works

Comment: So how are you passing the actual ID from the form to the script

Comment: i don't do that yet this is just to show what i want

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("video").click(function(){
        if (this.paused)
            document.getElementById('clickCounter').click();
        else
            this.pause()
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: but how do i upload the amount of clicks to the database? 
thank you for your answer btw :D